# toString.equals not working?

Tags: java, equals, tostring

I'm trying to get a comparison to work, and for the life of me I cannot figure out what is wrong.

```
StringL l = new StringL();
    l.insert("banana", 0);
    l.insert("orange", 1);
    l.insert("apple",  2);
    l.insert("pear", 3);
    if (!(l.toString().equals("banana, orange, apple, pear")));{
        System.out.println("Test failed: should have returned banana, orange, apple, pear but returned " + l.toString());}
}
```

However, when I run it, I get:

```
Test failed: should have returned banana, orange, apple, pear but returned banana, orange, apple, pear
```

ToString:

```
public String toString() {

        String result = ("") ;
        if(size() > 0) 
            result += stringList.get(0);

        for(int i = 1; i < size(); i++) 
            result += ", " + stringList.get(i);

        return result;
    }
```

Comment: Show us your `toString()`

Comment: edited to add toString.

Comment: What is class StringL?

Answer (score 7):

You have an extra `;` where you shouldn't

```
if (!(l.toString().equals("banana, orange, apple, pear")));{
                                                          ^
```

This ends up looking like

```
if (!(l.toString().equals("banana, orange, apple, pear")))
    ;
{
    System.out.println("Test failed: should have returned banana, orange, apple, pear but returned " + l.toString());
}
```

So the `if` executes the empty statement `;` if the condition is `true`. The block `{}` executes no matter what.

Comment: Also, when you print out an error message like that, do something like `... but returned >>" + whatever + "<<");` so that you can see exactly where the string begins and ends.

Comment: Could the downvoter please add a comment explaining why you think this answer is bad?

Comment: @CameronSkinner - Do understand that if a downvoter adds a comment he's setting himself up for possible "revenge" downvotes.  This certainly doesn't happen all the time and probably not very often at all, but it only takes one individual with a "stalker" mentality to make life unpleasant.

Comment: @HotLicks Truthfully, I'm harsh on answers that are wrong and questions where the author doesn't show effort. So I do think I get a few revenge downvotes (recently even). I'll still continue asking in case they are legitimate.

Comment: @HotLicks: I get that, but a downvote with no explanation is not helpful to anyone. I don't see anything wrong with this answer so understanding why it was downvoted would be very useful. Personally, I don't care if someone wants to take their petty revenge on me. Two points is worth understanding what I'm missing with this answer.

Comment: It's just annoying when someone downvotes you several times a day for a week.  And I worry a little that they'll figure out who I am and attack me other ways.  I don't really give a rip about the points.